# Can one symlink to a URL?

Tags: macos, operating-systems, symbolic-link

I have a CSS file that I'd like to symlink to an external CSS file.

The external CSS file is only available as a URL - it's not on my filesystem.

Is this possible?

I'm running OSX.

Comment: how often is the external css file updated?  Could you not just download it - at intervals if it will be updated?

Comment: @ColinPickard It's more suitable as a comment, converted it to a comment.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you can include it using this in the local CSS file:

```
@import url(http://www.foo.com/style.css);
```